# How many studs do I need for ~60 lbs TV + soundbar

Tags: mounting, studs, television

With the TV mount bracket I have, I can get it in 3 studs. If I need 4 studs I will need a bigger TV mount. My TV is 56 pounds and my sound bar (attached to TV) is 5 pounds. So I'm wondering if 3 studs is enough or if I need 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With proper anchors 3 studs are fine. One #10 wood screw penetrated 1" into cedar (the least quality of commercial lumber) will resist pull out of about 90 lbs, into most typical framing studs ([with a specific gravity greater than 0.45](https://www.zillarac.com/Portals/0/Documents/PDF/Screw%20Pull-out.pdf)) will hold 150 lbs.

Comment: I can only _imagine_ the lack of moth problems in a house framed with cedar studs! (I've never really thought of cedar as "lumber", especially when talking about hanging things from the wall, only as a drawer/chest material.)

Comment: @FreeMan :) Right, was really just documenting that wood density makes a difference!